# Select distinct option from MySQL

Tags: php, distinct, distinct-values

I have form with select option from MySQL table.
Because I want unique option I add SELECT DISTINCT...
But I have values like: R15 and R15C
now I want to combine this two to only 15 show in select option?

Curent code:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT diameter FROM tires WHERE cat = 'cars' ORDER BY diameter ASC"); while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){ $diameter = $rows['diameter']; ?>
<option value="<?php echo $diameter; ?>"><?php echo $diameter; ?></option>
```

Comment: you got to add some sample data, your question is not clear enough, we don't know what you want to combine and what should it be based on

Comment: You're going to try and fuzzy up the distinct query with something like this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165400/fuzzy-distinct-values

Comment: ok. currently i have in mysql... R13,R14,R13,R15,R15C,R16,R14,R15,.... with Select Distinct i get: R13,R14,R15,R15C,... but I want to get: R13,R14,R15,R16...thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just added this to make it work

```
AND premer NOT LIKE '%C%'
```